# fullCalendar, Syncronization with Outlook

Tags: outlook, calendar, synchronization, fullcalendar, angular-calendar

I work for an online booking company and I am relatively new to this field.
On out website we have a built-in calendar (we use Angular fullCalendar), from where all our clients can make an online booking. We already have a function to save the appointment in google calendar, outlook, etc via ics.file, which is sent by E-mail immediately after the appointment has been made. We are currently looking for an automatic synchronisation with Outlook. That is, the appointment that is made in our calendar should appear in Outlook automatically. I tried CalDav Synconizer, but I can't make any connection, because I don't have a link to direct the synchronization from. Is there another way to automatically connect to 2 calendars?
I would really appreciate it if you could help me with an idea.

Thank you very much!

Comment: If you're using Office365 then you can use the Microsoft graph API to insert events into the outlook calendar

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in mechanisms in Outlook for that. You are looking for any mechanisms that allow synchronizing with the server-side like Exchange. The best what you could do is to use EWS (see [Explore the EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/explore-the-ews-managed-api-ews-and-web-services-in-exchange)) or [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-mail-concept-overview) (in case of Office365).